# Next.js TypeError: (0 , firebase_auth__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.onAuthStateChanged) is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, typeerror

Im new to Next.js development. Im following a Youtube tutorial to build a Whatsapp clone.
Im using firebase8.9 as the database

I want to check if the user is logged in, then go to the home page else redirect to the login page.

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth"
import { auth, db } from "../firebase"
import Login from "./login"

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);

  

  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp
```

my firebase.js file

```
import firebase from 'firebase';


const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "apikey",
    authDomain: "authdomain",
    projectId: "projectid",
    storageBucket: "storagebucket",
    messagingSenderId: "messagingsenderid",
    appId: "appid"
  };


const app = !firebase.apps.length ? firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : firebase.app();

const db = app.firestore();

const auth = app.auth();

const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

export { db, auth, provider };
```

Please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

As the time, `firebase` version is upgraded as of now to version 9+ as well as the `firebase hooks` changing the entire structure. So, what you simply need to do is go to your `package.json` file and change your "firebase" version to `"firebase": "8.0.0"`.

Now look for "react-firebase-hooks" in the same `package.json` file and change its version to `"react-firebase-hooks": "^3.0.4"` from the current version.

Now, open up your terminal and run `yarn install`, this will solve the version issue.

Answer (score 0):

"firebase": "8.2.1",
"react-firebase-hooks": "^2.2.0",

this config worked for me. my react-firebase-hooks was ^5.0.0

Answer (score 0):

You can checks if the user has been authenticated. The user has been authenticated if "user" is not "null". The user has not been authenticated if "user" is "null".

Method 1

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth"
import { auth, db } from "../firebase"
import Login from "./login"

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);

  if (user) {
    return <Component {...pageProps} />;
  } else {
    return <Login />;
  }
}

export default MyApp
```

Method 2

The error will tell you where the issue.

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth"
import { auth, db } from "../firebase"
import Login from "./login"

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error}</div>;
  }

  if (!user) {
    return <Login />;
  }

  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp
```

Method 3

If the methods above failed. Wrap your "auth check" code in an "onAuthStateChange" function like this:

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth"
import { auth, db } from "../firebase"
import Login from "./login"

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(currentUser) {
      if (currentUser) {
        setUser(currentUser);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    });
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (user) {
    return <Component {...pageProps} />;
  } else {
    return <Login />;
  }
}

export default MyApp
```

The "currentUser" represents the authenticated user.

Answer (score -1):

Was stuck on the same error

Just go to the node modules and change the version of react-firebase-hook from 4.0.0 to 3.0.4.

And then a simple yarn install will solve the issue...

Comment: i've tried it, but still the same error.

Comment: Never edit the node modules. Do this change in the "package.json" instead.